# Volley post works only once with image and text to mysql db

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

I am posting 4 text and 1 image to mysql db using the Volley library. The code works only once after that i am getting only empty response when i try to post and no data is seen in the sql db as well. Added all the necessary permissions in the Android manifest as well but not able to fond what is wrong with this code.

JAVA:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

RadioButton radioType;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
EditText FoodName,FoodLocation,ShopName;
TextView Camera,Gallery,Post;
ImageView imageView;
private Bitmap bitmap;

private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
private String UPLOAD_URL ="http://xyz.ttt.com/upload.php";

private String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
private String KEY_NAME = "FoodName";
private String KEY_LOCATION = "FoodLocation";
private String KEY_SHOP = "ShopName";
private String KEY_TYPE = "Type";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup);
    FoodName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.FoodName);
    FoodLocation = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.FoodLocation);
    ShopName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ShopName);
    Camera = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Camera);
    Gallery = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Gallery);
    Post = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Post);
    imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    Camera.setOnClickListener(this);
    Gallery.setOnClickListener(this);
    Post.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == Gallery){
        showFileChooser();
    }
    if(v == Post){
        uploadImage();
    }
}

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}

private void uploadImage(){
    //Showing the progress dialog
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Uploading...","Please wait...",false,false);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    //Disimissing the progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();
                    //Showing toast message of the response
                    Toast.makeText(Main.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    //Dismissing the progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();

                    //Showing toast
                    Toast.makeText(Main.this, volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            //Converting Bitmap to String
            String image = getStringImage(bitmap);

            //Getting Image Name
            String FName = FoodName.getText().toString().trim();

            String FLocation = FoodLocation.getText().toString().trim();

            String SName = ShopName.getText().toString().trim();

            int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            radioType = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
            String rType = radioType.getText().toString().trim();


            //Creating parameters
            Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

            //Adding parameters
           params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
            params.put(KEY_NAME, FName);
            params.put(KEY_LOCATION, FLocation);
            params.put(KEY_SHOP, SName);
            params.put(KEY_TYPE, rType);


           //returning parameters
            return params;
        }
    };

    //Creating a Request Queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
} }
```

PHP:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    $image = $_POST['image'];
            $FoodName = $_POST['FoodName'];
            $FoodLocation = $_POST['FoodLocation'];
    $ShopName = $_POST['ShopName'];
            $Type = $_POST['Type'];

    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    $sql ="SELECT id FROM foodstore ORDER BY id ASC";

    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $id = 0;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            $id = $row['id'];
    }

    $path = "images/$id.png";

    $actualpath = "http://xyz.ttt.com/$path";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO foodstore (image,FoodName,FoodLocation,ShopName,Type) VALUES ('$actualpath','$FoodName','$FoodLocation','$ShopName','$Type')";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
        echo "Successfully Uploaded";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
```

What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: Are you getting any network response in the Android studio logcat if you set the view to verbose when you try to post again?

Comment: D/Volley﹕ [6720] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] http://xyz.ttt.com/upload.php 0x460c6660 NORMAL 1> [lifetime=3031], [size=0], [rc=200], [retryCount=0] and W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection

Comment: Doesn't seem to show a success or error response. Have you tried testing using WAMP or XAMPP?

Comment: Yes its an empty response. I am not aware of WAMP or XAMPP.

Comment: no worries. I'll explain it in the morning as well as test out your code. Basically those two programs allow you to test server side code on your local network prior to publishing.

Comment: [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) and [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) are both the best web development platforms for your computer. They allow you to test out web apps on your computer during development including MySql database queries. You can setup a local MySql database. I use it for testing my networked apps before going live.